# Replacing X9 10-speed shifter with GX 10-speed

Tags: shifter

I currently have a badly broken 10-speed X9 shifter.  I can replace it relatively cheaply, I think, with a GX 10-speed, available at a local store.  I believe that all 10-speed SRAM shifters are interchangeable, but I wanted to double check.  So, 2 questions:

1. Will this have any problems working with my X9 rear derailleur?
2. Vastly less important, but a curiosity... How similar to the X9 shifter would the feel and function be?  It seems to be about the same lever layout, but beyond that it's hard to tell.

Comment: A little information for future generations...  The replacement has been perfect, with no compatibility problems at all, as predicted by @JoeK.  The feel and function are nearly indistinguishable from the X9 I had.  The X9 is a long line of components, so I can only speak for my generation, but  it has been a painless transition with muscle memory having no problems in the switchover.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.compatability is 100 percent

2. Maybe not exactly the same but the Gx is a good shifter.
3. You can go 11speed with an Apex1 shifter plus 11sp cassette and chain. There is a reason why mtb 11/12 uses a new actuation ratio though.